# An if inside my If JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop

i'm having a problem about the if inside my if, because it does not read the if inside my if. It does only print the "if and goto detected" once i type for example ("if 1 goto A") then next line ("A:") . Supposedly when the program finds ":" it should print there's a colon but it won't print on mine .Please help me.

```
public turing() {
    String[] input = inputArea.getText().split("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if(input[i].startsWith("if")==true && (input[i].contains("goto")==true)){
            System.out.print("If and Goto detected");
            if(input[i].contains(":")==true){
                System.out.print("There's a Colon");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there are 4 `{`s and 3 `}`s in your posted codes, can you fix that first?

Comment: you don't close the { when you're in your 1st if block. When you reach the if(input[i].contains(":")==true), i has not changed, you're still comparing "if 1 goto A"

Comment: @StephaneM : as per my understanding, i see the code as , `IF starts with IF and has GOTO THEN ONLY CHECK if it contains ":"`...logically its fine!!

Answer (score 0):

You dont't close the if about "if" and "goto" before you open the one about ":", so ":" will only be reported if an "if" or "goto" is present.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another `if` because right now the program will only reach `System.out.print("There's a Colon");` if `if`, `goto`, **and** `:` are in the string. This would make your code as follows:

```
public turing() {
    String[] input = inputArea.getText().split("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if(input[i].startsWith("if")==true && (input[i].contains("goto")==true)){
            System.out.print("If and Goto detected");
        }
        if(input[i].contains(":")==true){
            System.out.print("There's a Colon");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

code is missing a closing bracket.
if you want the colon to be detected in all case, put the closing bracket after the first println, as in

```
    if (element.startsWith("if") == true
            && (element.contains("goto") == true)) {
        System.out.print("If and Goto detected");
    }
    if (element.contains(":") == true) {
        System.out.print("There's a Colon");
    }
```

otherwise, to get the colon only when in the if

```
    if (element.startsWith("if") == true
            && (element.contains("goto") == true)) {
        System.out.print("If and Goto detected");
        if (element.contains(":") == true) {
           System.out.print("There's a Colon");
        }
    }
```

Comment: He/she says `an if inside my if`, meaning they probably meant to not put a bracket there.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is wrong.

`if 1 goto A` prints `If and Goto detected` as it has an if and a goto. It doesn't print the colon part, as there is no colon.

Next your input is `A:`, it has no if and no goto, so it never passes the first if and will never reach the inner if.

If you enter `if 1 goto A:` then it will print both outputs.

So either change your input or change your logic. If you want to check for the colon independently, then you have to change the code like this:

```
public turing() {
    String[] input = inputArea.getText().split("\n");
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if(input[i].startsWith("if") && (input[i].contains("goto"))){
            System.out.print("If and Goto detected");
        }
        if(input[i].contains(":")){
            System.out.print("There's a Colon");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: even if i input If 1 goto A: .. Still it does not print the Colon detected

Comment: @marky: It won't if you write `if` with a capital `I`. But it should if you write it correctly. Oh, and please remove the `==true` if you want to compare a boolean.